# TFS build definition variable access for powershell script

Tags: tfs, powershell-3.0, msbuild-4.0

I checked around, but nothing is what I need. I am trying to convert my TFS 2013 build definitions from using custom actions to using powershell. So far, I have successful, but not I am trying to run an installshield build passing the iscmd build several custom variables from the build defintition such as Env, ProviderName, ProviderId, and Edition. In my old script, I did the following command using the activity RunMSbuild IIRC
msbuild project file "/p:PATH_TO_PIPELINE=""" + BuildDirectory + """ /p:Provider=""" + PROVIDER + """ /p:Edition=" + EDITION + " /p:Env=" + ENV + " /p:ProductVersion=" + BuildDetail.BuildNumber + " /p:ProviderId=" + PROVIDERID
I have been able to make PATH_TO_PIPELINE and Product version work using TF variables, but the others are not seen by powershell, not matter the ticks, quotes, etc. I use. Ideas on how I can make this work? I have variable on the build defintion for all of these.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your variables as custom $Env:MyVeriable to be able to access it. That is how the OOB ones work.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1035

Comment: I tried this using 
" /p:PATH_TO_PIPELINE=$Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY /p:ProductVersion=$Env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER /p:ENVIRONMENT=$Env:ENVIRONMENT /filelogger", but all my script comes back with is an empty variable for Env like this
IsCmdBld.exe -p "Raptor_Basic.ism" -r "SINGLE_EXE_IMAGE" -l "PATH_TO_PIPELINE=D:\Builds\2\Raptor\Dev_TS_Raptor_Installer\src" -z "ProductVersion=4.0.0.1361" -z "ENVIRONMENT=".
I also tried using the example in the link and get a PS error about
 At
 + ... p:ENVIRONMENT="$(Env:ENVIRONMENT)" /filelogger"
 Unexpected token '$(' in expression or statement.